# ! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character × (U+00D7)

Tags: errors, input-encodings

`$\ln{\frac{1}{×}}$`

I try to write this code for ln(1/x) but it doesn't matter,

I define some package for example `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`
but it doesn't matter really.

anyone can help me?

Comment: It looks like you have a multiplication sign (×) instead of x.

Comment: According to https://w3c.github.io/xml-entities/unicode-names.html the sign `×` is indeed `U+00d7 MULTIPLICATION SIGN`. You probably want a normal `x` (` U+0078 LATIN SMALL LETTER X`) instead. LaTeX is not set up to handle `×` by default, but you can add something like `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00D7}{\times}` to make it produce LaTeX's version of the times/multiplication symbol. But in this case it really looks as though you want an `x`.